# Modulo, align_up function assembly code x86

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I have the following generated assembly code that keeps crashing for some reason.

```
  0000000040001AF0: 48 8D 44 24 30     lea         rax,[rsp+30h]
  0000000040001AF5: 48 89 08           mov         qword ptr [rax],rcx
  0000000040001AF8: 48 8D 4C 24 38     lea         rcx,[rsp+38h]
  0000000040001AFD: 48 89 11           mov         qword ptr [rcx],rdx
  0000000040001B00: 48 8D 54 24 40     lea         rdx,[rsp+40h]
  0000000040001B05: 48 8B 28           mov         rbp,qword ptr [rax]
  0000000040001B08: 48 8B 31           mov         rsi,qword ptr [rcx]
  0000000040001B0B: 48 89 E8           mov         rax,rbp
  0000000040001B0E: 48 31 D2           xor         rdx,rdx
  0000000040001B11: 48 F7 F6           div         rax,rsi
  0000000040001B14: 48 89 D5           mov         rbp,rdx
  0000000040001B17: 48 8D 44 24 40     lea         rax,[rsp+40h]
  0000000040001B1C: 48 89 28           mov         qword ptr [rax],rbp
  0000000040001B1F: 48 8D 54 24 58     lea         rdx,[rsp+58h]
  0000000040001B24: 48 8B 28           mov         rbp,qword ptr [rax]
  0000000040001B27: 48 31 F6           xor         rsi,rsi
  0000000040001B2A: 48 63 F6           movsxd      rsi,esi
  0000000040001B2D: 48 39 F5           cmp         rbp,rsi
  0000000040001B30: BD 00 00 00 00     mov         ebp,0
  0000000040001B35: 0F 94 C5           sete        ch
  0000000040001B38: 48 83 FD 01        cmp         rbp,1
  0000000040001B3C: 0F 84 26 00 00 00  je          0000000040001B68
  0000000040001B42: 48 8D 6C 24 30     lea         rbp,[rsp+30h]
  0000000040001B47: 48 8B 6D 00        mov         rbp,qword ptr [rbp]
  0000000040001B4B: 48 8B 09           mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx]
  0000000040001B4E: 48 8B 00           mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]
  0000000040001B51: 48 29 C1           sub         rcx,rax
  0000000040001B54: 48 01 CD           add         rbp,rcx
  0000000040001B57: 48 89 2A           mov         qword ptr [rdx],rbp
  0000000040001B5A: 66 0F 1F 44 00 00  nop         word ptr [rax+rax]

  0000000040001B60: 48 8B 12           mov         rdx,qword ptr [rdx]
  0000000040001B63: 48 89 D0           mov         rax,rdx
  0000000040001B66: C3                 ret
  0000000040001B67: 90                 nop

  0000000040001B68: 48 8D 44 24 30     lea         rax,[rsp+30h]
  0000000040001B6D: 48 8B 00           mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]
  0000000040001B70: 48 89 02           mov         qword ptr [rdx],rax
  0000000040001B73: E9 E8 FF FF FF     jmp         0000000040001B60
```

This is generated by a program from the following pseudo-code function.

```
align_up(uint64 value, uint64 alignment) : uint64 {
    uint64 val = value
    uint64 algn = alignment
    // align to the next alignment boundary, if unaligned
    uint64 tmp = val % algn
    return (tmp == 0 ? val : val + (algn - tmp))
}
```

value and alignment are in `rcx` and `rdx` respectively.

Any ideas about why this code might be crashing would be greatly appreciated.

I know it is the above code that is the offending code as I can replace it with the following code and the program performs as expected.

```
  0000000040001AF0: 48 8D 44 24 30     lea         rax,[rsp+30h]
  0000000040001AF5: 48 89 08           mov         qword ptr [rax],rcx
  0000000040001AF8: 48 8D 4C 24 38     lea         rcx,[rsp+38h]
  0000000040001AFD: 48 89 11           mov         qword ptr [rcx],rdx
  0000000040001B00: 48 8D 54 24 40     lea         rdx,[rsp+40h]
  0000000040001B05: 48 8B 28           mov         rbp,qword ptr [rax]
  0000000040001B08: 48 8B 31           mov         rsi,qword ptr [rcx]
  0000000040001B0B: 48 89 E8           mov         rax,rbp
  0000000040001B0E: 48 31 D2           xor         rdx,rdx
  0000000040001B11: 48 F7 F6           div         rax,rsi
  0000000040001B14: 48 89 D5           mov         rbp,rdx
  0000000040001B17: 48 8D 44 24 40     lea         rax,[rsp+40h]
  0000000040001B1C: 48 89 28           mov         qword ptr [rax],rbp
  0000000040001B1F: 48 8B 10           mov         rdx,qword ptr [rax]
  0000000040001B22: 48 31 ED           xor         rbp,rbp
  0000000040001B25: 48 63 ED           movsxd      rbp,ebp
  0000000040001B28: 48 39 EA           cmp         rdx,rbp
  0000000040001B2B: BA 00 00 00 00     mov         edx,0
  0000000040001B30: 0F 94 C2           sete        dl
  0000000040001B33: 48 83 FA 01        cmp         rdx,1
  0000000040001B37: 0F 84 1B 00 00 00  je          0000000040001B58
  0000000040001B3D: 48 8D 54 24 30     lea         rdx,[rsp+30h]
  0000000040001B42: 48 8B 12           mov         rdx,qword ptr [rdx]
  0000000040001B45: 48 8B 09           mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx]
  0000000040001B48: 48 8B 00           mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]
  0000000040001B4B: 48 29 C1           sub         rcx,rax
  0000000040001B4E: 48 01 CA           add         rdx,rcx
  0000000040001B51: 48 89 D0           mov         rax,rdx
  0000000040001B54: C3                 ret
  0000000040001B55: 0F 1F 00           nop         dword ptr [rax]

  0000000040001B58: 48 8D 44 24 30     lea         rax,[rsp+30h]
  0000000040001B5D: 48 8B 00           mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]
  0000000040001B60: C3                 ret
  0000000040001B61: 0F 1F 80 00 00 00  nop         dword ptr [rax+0000000000000000h]
                    00
```

This makes me think this has something to do with the negative jump maybe???

Comment: Which instruction does the code crash at?

Comment: I can't tell, do you know of a debugger that could tell me?

Comment: `gdb` has the `backtrace` command for this purpose.

Comment: One thing that could be: `rbp` is normally a callee saved register.  But you don't save it.  So if the caller is a standard C function, it will missbehave.

Comment: `sete ch` before falling through into `mov rcx,qword ptr [rcx]` seems like problem; you nuke the 2nd byte of the pointer in RCX to 0 or 1.  Also, if you're branching on the condition anyway, you the boolean value should be a constant in either side. But IDK why your code is so complicated and has so many different pointers; https://godbolt.org/z/TdfE4o7Y5 shows compiler output.  (And if alignment is guaranteed a power of 2, you can make it *much* more efficient by optimizing `% align` into `& (align-1)`; as you can see, far fewer instructions, and no branching.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right! I would not have spotted that. Yes the code is needlessly complex. I am using a very early version of a compiler and it is built on some older code generation tools with no optimisation.

Comment: This has now been resolved. "sete ch before falling through into mov rcx,qword ptr [rcx]" is the problem if you write it as an answer then I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  //....
  0000000040001B2D: 48 39 F5           cmp         rbp,rsi
  0000000040001B30: BD 00 00 00 00     mov         ebp,0
  0000000040001B35: 0F 94 C5           sete        ch
  0000000040001B38: 48 83 FD 01        cmp         rbp,1
  //....
  0000000040001B4B: 48 8B 09           mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx]
  //....
```

As Peter Cordes said "`sete ch` before falling through into `mov rcx,qword ptr [rcx]`" seems like problem. This is the problem, the code sets the higher byte (second byte) of rcx before trying to load a value from rcx.

Comment: You might want to add how you did correct the code. What replaces `sete ch`?

Comment: Actually you can't change `sete ch`. But you can opt not to use `rcx` for loading from, instead using a different register. This is because the `sete` instruction only works with the first 4 registers but loading can be done from any register. The `mov ebp,0` and 
`cmp rbp,1` should be changed to use `rcx` for this to work.

Comment: There's no reason to materialize a boolean in CH anywhere.  The asm in the question is vastly over-complicated.  https://godbolt.org/z/cqaePf31n shows how simple GCC's and clang's outputs are for power-of-2 `algn`, and not much more complicated for rounding up to a multiple of an arbitrary number using `div` to get the remainder. https://godbolt.org/z/5aa8sjMbb    (Clang optimistically tries to use 32-bit operand-size for `div` because of Intel CPUs before Ice Lake, so it branches on that.)

Comment: Also, you can `sete` into any 8-bit register.  That includes [ABCD][LH] in any mode, and in long mode also SIL, DIL, BPL, SPL, R8L..R15L.